# Is there any way to merge two strings char by char using in c# using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

say i have two strings 
**string str1 = "SAKVRLW"**
**string str2 = "TCOEFO"**

The result i wanted is below

**result = "STACKOVERFLOW".**

Sorry if this is a basic question but i am new to Linq ? Any help/suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Start with str1.Zip(str2).

Comment: Very difficult, very **useless**.

Comment: Related: [Interleaved merge with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224511/interleaved-merge-with-linq)

Comment: My guess (without trying it) would be to use the ```.Zip()``` LINQ method.

Comment: `Zip` will get you some of the way, but this is complicated by your two strings being different lengths.  You can get *STACKOVERFLO* quite easily.  But, as @xanatos says, what's the point?!

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thanks..I got an idea

Comment: Why restrict yourself to linq, linq is just shortcut methods for stuff you could do in a `foreach` or `for` loop. Solve your problem with a `for` loop first then come back and ask how would I turn this `for` loop in to linq (but first ask yourself do you really need to convert it at all?)

Comment: Sometime LINQ is elegant and sometime it is fast and sometimes it is both; sometimes is better quality (eg.g: when sorting). And sometimes it is none of the above..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes u are correct..I did it with foreach only, but was curious to know if i can achieve this using linq

Comment: I stopped using `For` and `Foreach` loops roughly 5 years ago; really. I fully use Linq for processing lists of information. Why is that valuable? Because a majority of programming tasks are processing lists of data and the extension methods via the use of the dyanmic lambda expressions is so powerful. Don't let anyone dissuade you from learning a powerful tool. IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the heart of this linq query is getting the index number from the select statement to use as an indexer into the other array.

Then its a matter of checking for an out of bounds condition while processing the char arrays into strings to be joined.

```
var str1 = "SAKVRLW";
var str2 = "TCOEFO";

var array2 = str2.ToCharArray();

string.Join(string.Empty, 
            str1.ToCharArray()
                .Select ((ch, index) => string.Format("{0}{1}", 
                                                       ch, 
                                                       index < array2.Length 
                                                       ? array2[index].ToString() 
                                                       : string.Empty  
                                                     )
                        )
           )
```

Outputs: `STACKOVERFLOW`

---

Using the above `Select` (projection) with an `Aggregate` instead of `string.Join` can be done as such

```
str1.ToCharArray()
    .Select ((ch, index) => string.Format("{0}{1}", ch, index < array2.Length ? array2[index].ToString() : string.Empty  ))
    .Aggregate ((seed, sentance) => seed + sentance )
```

Outputs: `STACKOVERFLOW`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it:

```
string str1 = "SAKVRLW";
string str2 = "TCOEFO";

str1.ToCharArray()
    .Select((ch, ix)=> new { ch=ch, ix = ix*2 })
    .Concat(  str2.ToCharArray().Select((ch, ix)=> new { ch=ch, ix = ix*2 +1 }))
    .OrderBy(x=>x.ix) 
    .Select(x=>x.ch)
    .Aggregate("", (s,c)=>s+c).Dump();
```

Comment: This works smooth..Thanks alot ... and this .Dump() is LinqPad extension method used for rendering object in console.

Comment: I like your `Aggregate`...but I used the index into the other array in my answer.